# CodeIgniter - $this->db->from did not add 'from x_table' to final query, failed several times over full navigation of site

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am seeing some very strange behavior today and I do not know what to make of it. We've been using codeigniter on our site for more than a year now and today when I clicked on one of our pages I saw a database error shown to me. I quickly opened up the controller for that page and refreshed to see it again but it did not happen this time, and I couldn't get it to trigger there again.

Hmm, alarming.

I navigated to a few other pages and it happened again on another, this time I looked at where it failed and it died on a query like this:

```
SELECT `foo`.`ID_NO` JOIN `bar` ON `bar`.`foo_ID` = `foo`.`ID_NO` WHERE `someSetting` = 0 AND `bar`.`Filter_ID` = '123'
```

...wait a second, where's the 'FROM foo' that should be in there?

I looked at my models controller and the following lines of code are what it tried to execute:

```
$this->db->select("foo.ID_NO");
$this->db->from('foo');
$this->db->join('bar','bar.foo_ID = foo.ID_NO');
```

This is code that has worked for a year and an error like this, anywhere, has not occurred before. It very much appears as though "$this->db->from('foo');" simply didn't happen.

I navigated to a bunch of other pages on the site and it happened a few times more, again same problem where the query wasn't being built correctly and a database error was thrown. When refreshed the error always went away. I haven't seen a repeat on any pages, nor have I seen a page pass then fail at a later time.

There are two things that maybe could be a factor: First, I recently added an error/exception handler (But that shouldn't have an impact on this, especially not once and then not again as far as I can tell).

Second, when I started using the error/handler I found an error in CodeIgniters that was known and was fixed by changing "function is_loaded($class = '')" to "function &is_loaded($class = '')" in Common.php because of an error that happened in Loader.php: "$this->_base_classes =& is_loaded();". That fix seemed to be widely accepted, and the error I'm experiencing is not repeatable and doesn't seems related so I also don't believe that is the cause.

I am using CodeIgniter version 2.1.2. Has anyone seen anything like this before? I can't imagine what the cause of this is but I would hate for it to happen outside the dev environment where I saw it happen today.

EDIT: Also, my fancy new error logging system I mentioned did not log anything that went wrong in the db->from function :(

Comment: Progress: There was an error happening in the code between the place db->select, db->from etc. were set up and the following db->get call so it was going to the error logger. The error logger does a query for duplicates before inserting into the DB. I suspect the insert statement that happens if the error is new ruins the query that was being built and caused my error. Mystery identified, just gotta fix it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause was my error catcher getting triggered due to referencing an index that didn't exist:

```
if($post_array['query'] != ""){
```

The error logger then gathered it's info and inserted into the database. I guess that it uses the same $this->db->ar_from field when you insert this way:

```
$this->db->insert('error_logging', $data);
```

Then clears it out afterwards as it does after any successful query.

The code then returned to it's previous position, with it's ar_select, ar_like, etc. fields intact but not ar_from and moved onto the $this->db->get() command which failed.

On subsequent page loads the error was already logged in the db and so a new insert was not performed and the query builder was not tampered with, and so no new database errors.

The fix was to simply get a clone of $this->db and use that clone to perform the insert.